# Rotacionar Foto Com Zend Image

Tags: zend

Preciso fazer uma verificação de orientação de uma foto para depois rotacionar a mesma.

E relação da orientação já conseguida, não foi encontrada rotacionando uma foto.

Estou usando Zend_Image e Zend_Image_Transform

Comment: Poste o que já foi tentado para conseguirmos dar um auxílio.

Comment: Tentei achar alguma propriedade do Zend_Image_Transform que fizesse isso.

Comment: E o carregamento dessa imagem, é feita através de `<canvas>`? Pois pode-se rotacionar essa TAG

Comment: Não, e um form input onde denho um metodo que salva a foto no banco de dados